# Cpplint and CMake - Treat warnings are errors and fail

Tags: cmake, cpplint

I'm using cpplint with CMake:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT cpplint;
    --filter=-build/include_subdir,-legal/copyright;
    --quiet)
```

But even if cpplint produces some warnings, the build is still successful.
I cannot find a way to treat those warnings as error (similarly to when using `-warnings-as-errors` for clang-tidy) and fail the build instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake always ignores the cpplint exit code.

Source code:

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blame/master/Source/cmcmd.cxx#L324